# Adding an "Edit Button" to the top of UITableController "at later stage"

Tags: ios

I've discovered at later stage that I need to add an "Edit button" to the top of UITableController view. 
what is the best way. if possible I don't want to do lots of changes to my application because it's almost done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a UIBarButtonItem to your navigation bar and invoke the editing mode of the table view in the action.

```
- (IBAction) edit:(id)sender {
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```